# How to find out the required window size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a window containing a label w whose text can be any of a given variety (in this case "Hello World! " once, twice and thrice):

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
text = "Hello, World! "
w = Label(root)

for i in range(1, 4):

    w["text"] = text*i
    w.update_idletasks()
    w.grid()
    w.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)

root.mainloop()
```

I would like to set the size of the window to a fixed width. This width should be the one which is required for the longest text that w can get. How can I do this most easily? Do I have to cycle through all possible texts, read the respective window width and set the final width to the maximum of these values? If this is the best way, how can I do this without the window appearing on the screen?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. There is `font measure` subcommand in Tk which returns pixel width of a string, but then you have to account for borders and the like. And there is `winfo reqwidth` for labels, but I'm not sure that `update idletasks` is not required between label text updates.

Answer (score 1):

How can you know the size of the largest text if you don't cycle through them ? The only possibility would be knowing the size of each one earlier, but then you would have solved the problem already. Therefore all you have to do is set the label and check the required width for the window, then you check whether this width is larger than the current maximum and update it if needed. If the window happens to show during this process, you can call `withdraw`, do everything you need, and then call `deiconify`.

```
import time
import random
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

text = "Hello, World! "
w = Tkinter.Label()
w.grid()

maxwidth = 0
for _ in range(10):
    i = random.randint(1, 5)
    w["text"] = text*i
    print i
    w.update_idletasks()
    maxwidth = max(maxwidth, root.winfo_reqwidth())

root.wm_minsize(maxwidth, root.winfo_reqheight())
root.wm_maxsize(maxwidth, int(1e6))
root.deiconify()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `winfo_reqwidth()` seems to be the solution. It is true that all possible texts must be checked for their required width. However, `winfo_reqwidth()` does not change the window width (if I am not mistaken) but tells which window width would be required. The window can be resized at the end as it is shown in the example above.

Comment: I know `winfo_reqwidth` doesn't change the window width, that is not it is used for. `wm_minsize` and `wm_maxsize` are being used for that. The window can still be resized vertically, I don't understand what you are complaining about. Can you be more clear on how this answer doesn't completely solve the problem ? It is setting the window's width to the largest width required for the largest label.

Comment: This code will come up with a different answer every time, somewhere between 1 and 5 times the length of "Hello, World!". I'm confused about how that constitutes a fixed width.

Comment: @Junuxx do you see the results of `print i` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed width for the label, and wrap the text using the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module. `textwrap.wrap(text, width)` will split `text` into lines no longer than `width` characters. It also has options for breaking   long words or hyphens, but see the documentation for that.

[image]

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import textwrap

root = Tk()
text = "Hello, World! "
w = Label(root, width=35)
w.grid()

for i in range(1, 4):
    w.update()
    s = text*i 
    s = "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(s, 21))

    w["text"] = s
    time.sleep(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `textwrap` might be a good solution for keeping a fixed width but it will influence the height of the window.

Comment: @Michael: That's true. You could make the height fixed as well. If you don't have an upper bound on the length of the text, you could add a scrollbar to make sure all the text is readable.

Comment: @Junuxx why are you bothering to call so many `update_idletasks` and `grid` given you already decided a width for the label (which clearly goes against the question) ?

Comment: @mmgp: Oh, right. I just copied and the code from the OP and made some modifications without cleaning up. Edited.